# VSTO Addin Code Signing | Security Question

Tags: c#, security, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I would like to use the best security coding practices in a `VSTO` Addin project I am implementing for `Microsoft Outlook` application and I have a question regarding code signing.

Following the creation of a code signing certificate (*.pfx*), I have successfully signed:

a) the **DLL** files produced by my project via using Visual Studio *post-build event parameters*.

b) the **EXE** & **MSI** installers using the `SignTool` command-line tool.

c) **<"filename">.vsto** and **<"filename">.dll.manifest** files

My question is that I used `mage` tool (Manifest Generation and Editing Tool) to **sign** the **<"filename">.VSTO** and **<"filename">.dll.manifest** files via the following commands - according to Microsoft:

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\....\mage.exe" -sign "<filename>.dll.manifest" -CertFile <certificate.pfx> -Password <password>
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\....\mage.exe" -update "<filename>.vsto" -appmanifest "<filename>.dll.manifest" --CertFile <certificate.pfx> -Password <password>
```

Verified that the relevant files have a ***"valid signature"*** after viewing the output of the following commands; apart from Visual Studio build output (reporting successful signing):

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\......\mage.exe" -ver "<filename>.vsto"
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\......\mage.exe" -ver "<filename>.dll.manifest"
```

However, when I check their properties via the windows explorer I do not see any "***Digital Signatures***" tab, not sure if this is the proper setting?

Am I missing something? Please let me know if there is anything I could additionally do to enhance the security posture of my `VSTO` Addin project.

Thank you.

References:

- https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/master/docs/deployment/how-to-re-sign-application-and-deployment-manifests.md
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/mage-exe-manifest-generation-and-editing-tool
- [Pre and Post Build event parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834663/pre-and-post-build-event-parameters)

Comment: Could you please add some information how to do steps a) and b)? I think this will be useful because there seems to be a lot of contradictory information out there. Also shouldn't the sequence be a), c), b)? Instead of a) why did you not go for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-sign-office-solutions?view=vs-2022 ? Thanks for any input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see digital signature in Windows Explorer only for the executable (dll and exe) files.

VSTO is a text file (try to open it in Notepad).

Comment: Hey,  thank you for your response, It is my very first Miicrosoft Addin and I am not very familiar with VSTO. You are right as it appears it contains XML data. So you think that everything is in accordance with the best practices? I am worried of any potential tampering of the Addin I have implemented this is the reason I want to code sign every possible file of the Addin.

Comment: Yes, that sounds fine to me.